Equivalent of ActiveRecord eager_load but with dynamic condition in join
I use MyTable.eager_load(:myjointable) as part of a query that fetches many rows. Now I want to specify a condition in the join clause created by eager_load.
I don't want it to be in the where clause, for performance reasons.
Specifying a condition in the join can be done with custom SQL, e.g. joins("left outer join myjointable on mytable.id = myjointable.mytable_id AND myjointable.created_at > ...".
Unfortunately if I do this ActiveRecord forgets about the columns on myjointable, and I am back to N+1 queries when I try to use mytableresults.first.myjointable.a_column.
If I add select("mytable.*, myjointable.*") Rails doesn't know how to instantiate the MyTable models and I get:
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/mytables", :id=>#}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id])
I see this question, where a static condition is applied as follows:
class Parent
  has_many :children
  has_many :grades, through: :children
  has_many :highest_grade, ->{where(level: 'A+')}, class_name: "Grade", through: :children
end

Parent.eager_load(:highest_grades)

This is almost what I want (it looks like Rails ends up moving the where clause into a join when passing the association to eager_loads):
# SELECT `parents`.`id` AS t0_r0, `parents`.`created_at` AS    t0_r1, `parents`.`updated_at` AS t0_r2, `grades`.`id` AS t1_r0,    `grades`.`child_id` AS t1_r1, `grades`.`created_at` AS t1_r2, `grades`.`updated_at` AS t1_r3, `grades`.`level` AS t1_r4 FROM `parents` LEFT OUTER JOIN `children` ON `children`.`parent_id` = `parents`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `grades` ON `grades`.`child_id` = `children`.`id` AND `grades`.`level` = 'A+'...

This is perfect except I need to be able to specify the criteria on the association dynamically.
How can I have:

eager loading
a condition on the join clause, not the where clause
the condition specified dynamically
no confusion from ActiveRecord about what columns to load into memory
not explicit listing every single column

I don't mind Arel or custom SQL, first prize is to just have small amounts that I can mix into normal ActiveRecord.

You can't actually do this with any of the eager loading methods in the query interface. Your best bet is to either work around the problem or load the data manually and then mark the association as loaded. You're not going to get your laundry list of requirements without it getting messy.

Why not Parent.eager_load(children: :grades).where(grades: {level: ["A+",nil]})? @max's comment is correct that you cannot modify or override the joins created by eager_load as they are implicit based on the associations. I guess you could possibly use an anonymous class for this e.g. Class.new(Parent) { has_many :highest_grade, ->{where(level: 'A+')}, class_name: 'Grade', through: :children}.eager_load(:highest_grade) but I wouldn't recommend it.

Why not use where: writing the SQL manually, I can see that a query with conditions in the join clause is much faster than a query with conditions in the where clause. The latter is not a big improvement on the former.

When you say "the condition specified dynamically", you mean you want to pass params to the lambda or you want to pass a lambda as parameter to the has_many relation?

I want to pass params to the lambda
